# Asp.net MVC 4 Multiple Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm beginer in asp.net mvc. I try the routing. but all route formats using by first defined route value. Example all views url finishing with "index" i don't want this url format. and  i want `localhost:56609/Cuisines/Detail/4/thai` but program showing `localhost:56609/Cuisines/getCuisineDetail/6/thai` . How to do this explain me please.

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    name:="RestaurantDetail", _
    url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Restaurants", .action = "Index", .id =     UrlParameter.Optional, .title = UrlParameter.Optional} _
)

routes.MapRoute( _
    name:="Cuisines", _
    url:="{controller}/Detail/{id}/{title}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Cuisines", .action = "getCuisineDetail", .id = UrlParameter.Optional, .title = UrlParameter.Optional} _
)

routes.MapRoute( _
    name:="Default", _
    url:="{controller}/{action}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"} _
)
```

View

```
   @<p>@Html.ActionLink(Model(i).Name, "getCuisineDetail", New With {.id = Model(i).CusineID, .title = OnlineSiparis.UrlEditor.CheckUrl(Model(i).Name)}) </p>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "RestaurantDetail" route also matches the URL pattern of the more specific "Cuisines" route. Try to change the code so that "Cuisines" is mapped first...

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    name:="Cuisines", _
    url:="{controller}/Detail/{id}/{title}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Cuisines", .action = "getCuisineDetail", .id = UrlParameter.Optional, .title = UrlParameter.Optional} _
)

routes.MapRoute( _
    name:="RestaurantDetail", _
    url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Restaurants", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional, .title = UrlParameter.Optional} _
)
```

Comment: Yes its works thank you. But i dont understand why cuisines route must  first

Comment: Because "RestaurantDetail" also matches the pattern specified by "Cuisines" route and the routing provider checks the routes in order, the first one that is mapped will "win". Therefore you have to map the "Cuisines" route first if you want it to match on `"{controller}/Detail/{id}/{title}"` (`@Html.ActionLink(Model(i).Name, "getCuisineDetail"` uses the same method to generate the link).